# How to drag a label only on SVG path in React

Tags: reactjs, svg, drag-and-drop, react-flow

I am using ReactFlow and I want to drag label only on SVG Path.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elastic-tdd-skl3ph.

In this example I want to drag "edge label" only on edge present between Node 1 and Node 2.